# Mysql does not accept \\xD1 even though I use utf8mb4

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL returns the following error when I want to execute a statement:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xD1' for column 'last_update' at row 1

Here is the code to insert the value:

```
$connection = DataBase\MySQLConnect::getConnection(self::$dbName);
$query  = "INSERT "
        . " into `answer` "
        . " ( "
        . " `reference`, "
        . " `language`, "
        . " `date`, "
        . " `info`, "
        . " `body`, "
        . " `url_html`, "
        . " `url_word`, "
        . " `url_pdf`, "
        . " `last_update` "
        . " ) "
        . " VALUE "
        . " ("
        . " :reference, "
        . " :language, "
        . " :date, "
        . " :info, "
        . " :body, "
        . " :url_html, "
        . " :url_word, "
        . " :url_pdf, "
        . " :last_update "
        . " )";
$stmt = DataBase\MySQLConnect::prepare($query, $connection);
DataBase\MySQLConnect::bindParam($stmt, ':reference', $this->fields['reference'], 'str');
DataBase\MySQLConnect::bindParam($stmt, ':language', $this->fields['language'], 'str');
DataBase\MySQLConnect::bindParam($stmt, ':date', $this->fields['date'], 'str');
DataBase\MySQLConnect::bindParam($stmt, ':info', $this->fields['info'], 'str');
DataBase\MySQLConnect::bindParam($stmt, ':body', $this->fields['body'], 'str');
DataBase\MySQLConnect::bindParam($stmt, ':url_html', $this->fields['url_html'], 'str');
DataBase\MySQLConnect::bindParam($stmt, ':url_word', $this->fields['url_word'], 'str');
DataBase\MySQLConnect::bindParam($stmt, ':url_pdf', $this->fields['url_pdf'], 'str');
DataBase\MySQLConnect::bindParam($stmt, ':last_update', $this->fields['last_update'], 'str');

$boolContinue = DataBase\MySQLConnect::execute($stmt);
```

All the static functions use PDO. I just added log writing.

The connection is created using PHP PDO and I bind the value.
I also use utf8mb4 charset both in the connection and table, and collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci in the table.

I tried with utf8mb4_unicode_ci but the error remains the same.

Could someone help me on this topic, please?
I have read a lot of discussions about similar cases but I did not find any efficient solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the character this one:  Ñ ? Normally this should not be part of a date field

Comment: `last_update` Is that a DATE or DATETIME column?

Comment: Can you please post your code and the value you are inserting?

Comment: What is the locale in the OS where PHP code is executed?

Comment: Sorry, I did not precise but the field is a VARCHAR, not a DATE or a DATETIME.
The value is "Последно осъвременяване: 24 януари 2022 г."
And which part of the code do you need?

Comment: I tried - it is unreproducible. (a normal varchar db table utf8xx field can store the string "Последно осъвременяване: 24 януари 2022 г.")

Comment: After the htmlspecialchars de PHP:

&lt;span class=&quot;text-muted&quot;&gt;\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe \xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x8a\xd0\xb2\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8f\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5: 24 \xd1\x8f\xd0\xbd\xd1\x83\xd0\xb0\xd1

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code related to the insert query. (minimal but reproducible code snippet please)

Comment: I just added it to the question.

Comment: `D1` is indeed not a valid UTF-8 character. Encodings are like languages: declaring that a Russian book is written in English won't translate it automagically. Is your editor configured to save files as UTF-8? Are your existing files actually saved as UTF-8? Do you mention UTF-8 anywhere when you connect to MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution and it was not a problem of character encoding.

In fact, to avoid Mysql errors when inserting a too long value, a function shortens them if necessary.
And this was the case for the Bulgarian value because PHP htmlspecialchar made it much longer than the column size.

As a result, the encoding was inconsistent and could not be inserted.

Anyway, thank you very much for your reactivity and your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try executing following query before executing insert query. I remember having similar issue which was resolved by running the following query after connection initializing;

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```